# How do I convert a boost::beast's response<buffer_body> to a response<string_body>?

Tags: c++, http, boost, boost-beast

I need to convert `boost::beast::http::response<boost::beast::http::buffer_body>` to `boost::beast::http::response<boost::beast::http::string_body>`.

What's an elegant and efficient way of doing so using beast's api?

P.S.

I think serializing and parsing is not so efficient, and maybe there's a better way. But if that's the solution, since I'm new to beast I would be also glad to see an elegant code example for that.

Thanks,
David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I managed to do it

```cpp
boost::beast::http::response<boost::beast::http::string_body> string_response;
boost::beast::http::response<boost::beast::http::buffer_body> buffer_response;
std::string response_body

// Do stuff to read the response and fill the response_body using the buffer

string_response.base() = buffer_response.base();
string_response.body() = response_body;
```

It turns out that the header has a copy constructor, so all I had to do is assign the string body..

So if the copy constructor is efficient (odds are that it is), this solution is also efficient.

Comment: hi david, Could you please share the code how you are reading and writing using boost beast even i am facing issues for converting stringbody to ostringstrem or a normal string.